# Отключен или отключён?

Tags: орфография, е-или-ё

Как правильно "сайт отключ**е**н" или "сайт отключ**ё**н"?
Может ли это зависеть от существительного или дополнительных слов в предложении?

[Исходная проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9392/176217).

Comment: @shampar выделение буквы регистром не приветствуется? Вроде бы суть вопроса лучше воспринимается из заголовка в исходном варианте.

Comment: Тогда, как мне кажется, нужно было выделить не Е, а якобы ударную гласную: *отклЮчен* или *отключЁн*.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец может быть, но вопрос не в ударении, а в букве. Ударение - это уже следствие.

Comment: **Выделение буквы регистром**, наверное, не от хорошей жизни происходит. Но здешний редактор, вполне приличный, позволяет выделять знаки инструментами, которые словá не уродуют.

Comment: @shampar форматирование в **заголовке** вопроса не работает вообще-то.

Comment: Так посчитали разработчики, сэкономили: вполне приличный — не блестящий. Блестящий в некоторых местах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (Большой орфоэпический словарь под ред. Каленчук и др.)

Вроде бы с точки зрения произношения верен только вариант с ё. Без ё писать можно, но только учитывая необязательность этой буквы в целом.

Comment: А какого года словарь? С 2012 года форма отклю'ченный стала допустимой. И, несколько я знаю, в впервые эта форма появилась именно в этом словаре.

Comment: @Серж Это словарь 2012 г.

Comment: Странно, что формы "отклЮчен," там нет.

Comment: @Серж Она имплицирована в ряду неправильных, так что в каком-то смысле есть

Comment: Я имею в виду, что в 2012 г. эту форму разрешили. Остальное в ответе guaranteen

Answer (score 2):

Ключ, ключик, ключник, уключина (опора лодочного весла), отключка (потеря сознания) – существительные с корнем «ключ», в которых ударение падает на корневую гласную.  (Можно ли продолжить этот немногочисленный ряд?).
При склонении слова «ключ» по падежам, числам и при образовании других частей речи корневая гласная «ю» (в подавляющем большинстве случаев) становится безударной.
Для глаголов с корнем «ключ» словарной нормой стала недопустимость постановки ударения на корневую «ю».
В 2012 году «Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка» впервые назвал ударение «вклю́чит» допустимым, до этого оно запрещалось всеми изданиями. [Владимир Пахомов. Без паники (12.01.2018) // «Сноб», 2018]
Почему разрешили ударение на Ю? Во-первых, «вклю́чит» соответствует языковым законам. [Владимир Пахомов. Без паники (12.01.2018) // «Сноб», 2018]
https://snob.ru/entry/156532/
«1) ВключИм, включИт, включАт и допустимо вклЮчим, вклЮчит, вклЮчат (согласно Большому орфоэпическому словарю М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткина, Р. Ф. Касаткиной 2012 г.).
НО!
2) ПодключИт/отключИт, подключИм/отключИм, подключАт/отключАт, заключАт, исключАт.
Согласно правилу, в русском языке на корень -ключ- ударение не падает, если говорить о глаголах. Пока только «включит» удостоилось такой чести, остальные глаголы стоят в очереди на изменение литературной нормы. Похоже, что вскоре это аксиому придётся пересмотреть».
https://pulse.mail.ru/article/10-pravilnyh-udarenij-kotorye-mnogih-udivlyayut-1784720704299269049-1455058762870749629/